# RecycleView get cuts at Bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This question is raised by so many people but for my case those solution and tips are not working.

I'm using RecycleView in fragment to display gridview for product display but is't cut last item at bottomside, I have gone through many solution like **android:clipToPadding="false" and android:paddingBottom="myactionbarsize"** but eventually it's doen't work.

Have a look at my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll_parent_vendors"
    android:background="@color/bg_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_vendors"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_empty_vendors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/edt_hint_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeNormal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my item Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_row_vendor_services"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp">


    <com.customview.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_vendor_services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_service_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/edt_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_service_price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_chat"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_chat"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and how I initialize in my fragment

```
rv_vendors = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_vendors);
rv_vendors.setHasFixedSize(true);
rv_vendors.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2));
```

Here are my Screenshot of emulator Pixel API 24 which cuts the layout at bottom.

[image]

and other one which is MIA1 real device Screenshot it's perfect with same propertie.

[image]

how this happens any hints ?

Comment: Have you tried, `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` ? Can you show the screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån have a look i have updated the que.

Comment: post your item xml.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya check now ..!

Comment: Have you tried by applying fix size to `ll_row_vendor_services` ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I have tried it but still same thing in result !

Comment: @HardikKubavat put **toolbar** in layout instead of **actionbar**. And constraint the recyclerview to bottom of toolbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183046/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-hardik-kubavat).